# In Google Sheets Add-ons, how do I check if the user has purchased the subscription?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps-script-addon

I have written a Google Sheets Add-on that I would like to monetize. Within the Apps Script .gs files, I cannot figure out how to query the Chrome Web Store to check if the user has made a payment for my add-on. The closest thing I can find is here:

https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/payments-iap

It says that I need to add a buy.js file to my app; however, there is no .gs equivalent and I could not figure out how to modify the contents of buy.js to get it to work within Apps Scripts.

If anyone knows how to check for users' payments within Apps Scripts, I would really appreciate sharing the info.

Comment: The Payments Merchant Account doesn't work in a Google Sheets Add-on.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add payment integration with Google Docs Add-ons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50279701/how-to-add-payment-integration-with-google-docs-add-ons)

Comment: See https://github.com/andrewroberts/Subs